# Javascript Callback from Paypal

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

Is there a way to get a Javascript callback from a successful PayPal purchase using a button?  I know about IPN, but that involves a return URL.  I really just want to know if a user bought something with the button.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the IPN call from Paypal is a one-time thing.  I think you would have to store the result of the IPN call from Paypal in your database.  Then, you can show the user the status of the transaction when they hit the button by way of a query to your database.